# How does one build an authentication RoR API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, oauth

Using Ruby on Rails, I've been trying to find best practices for building an authentication API in order to ensure security. Are there guidelines or aspects I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use gems for authentication Devise or AuthLogic. They're quite good, have a lot of functionality and are extendable. Devise has RESTful API. Have a look inside the code.